# MAP to POP3 conversion - looking for a way to move messages from old mailbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am trying to convert an IMAP to a POP3 email account on an outlook 2016 client. Every page I've bupmbed to mentions pretty much the same process: 1) create your POP3 account, 2) move all messages and data to your your newly created POP3 account, 3) then delete IMAP. Problem is, apparently in the client version I am using, that's not directly possible: when I go to add a POP3 account, I get a message saying "this email address has already being added", and it just won't let me carry on. Some user posted the same and he got the suggestion to first create a new profile, then attach to it the POP3 account. I did that. Specifically:

1. I exported a .pst file from the already existing IMAP account to a local folder
2. I created a second profile and added the POP3 account
3. I used the option use existing pst file in order to load all messages from the old account.

While it loaded `calendar`and `tasks` folders with all pre-exsting data, that didn't happen with the emails from the inbox and sent folders, the most important ones. Since new POP3 belongs to new profile the old IMAP mailbox tree  won't appear in the `Folder Pane` of that new profile, therefor it's neither a matter of just selecting and moving items betweeen folder trees.

Practically, I am stuck with this one. How to move all emails safely from the old account mailbox to the newly POP3 mailbox.

And I would so much appreciate any help with that!

Comment: For the new email account, instead of "using" the PST (I know what this means), "import" the PST file. Delete the email account, set it up again, and then in Outlook, File Import and import the PST file

Comment: @John Just set up the new account selecting the option "create a new pst file", then import the pst of the old account. I'll try that out, hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: Export PST from IMAP account and import the PST file to your POP account not directly "using" .